# Prefered scenario to update one-to-many (both One and Manies should be updated)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the recommended way to update both Book and Pages in this one-to-many scenario (EF Core)?

A book contains one or more pages.
Each page belongs to one book only, and pages don't exist on their own.

The entities:

```
class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string ISBN {get; set;}
    
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages {get; set;}
}

class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

method to update an existing book:

```
/// <summary>
/// Save an existing book including pages
/// </summary>
public void SaveExistingBook(Book bookToUpdate)
{
    var bookEntity = _databaseContext.Books.Including(b => b.Pages).SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookToUpdate.Id);
    ... etc....
}
```

The bookToUpdate parameter contains all the book properties and pages with their properties as they should become.
(Properties of the book (Title, ISBN) might have changed, as well as properties on pages (Text changes).
Also, pages might have been added or deleted.)

What is the proper way to implement such a method?

1. Delete the original book with pages and insert a new book and pages?
2. Iterate through all the pages and remove/insert deleted/new pages and update properties on changed pages. Update properties of the book.
3. Other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through many records to update is not recommended due to performance issues, the entities needs to be loaded then perform the update operation, that is a time and performance consuming process.

The best approach is to use a third party library like [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/), it offers [batch update](https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update) and [batch delete](https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-delete).

So, for your case all you have to do is to create the conditional update expression and call the batch update method:

```cs
_databaseContext.Books.Where(b => b.Id == bookToUpdate.Id)
                      .Update(b => /* your update expression */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my prefered way to update the one-to-many relation:

```
public void SaveExistingBook(Book bookToUpdate)
{
    var bookInDb = _databaseContext.Books.Including(b => b.Pages).FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == bookToUpdate.Id);
    if (bookInDb == null) return;

    // First update book properties
    bookInDb.Name = bookToUpdate.Name;
    //...

    // Delete all removed pages
    var pagesToDelete = (from page in bookInDb.Pages
                         let item = bookToUpdate.Pages.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == page.Id)
                         where item == null
                         select page).ToList();

    if (pagesToDelete.Any())
        foreach (var page in pagesToDelete)
            _databaseContext.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    // Add all new pages
    foreach (var page in bookInDb.Pages.Where(p => p.Id < 1).ToList())
    {
        page.BookId = bookInDb.Id;
        _databaseContext.Pages.Add(page);
    }

    // Modify existing pages
    foreach (var pageToUpdate in bookInDb.Pages.Where(p => p.Id > 0 && pagesToDelete.All(pg.Id == p.Id)).ToList())
    {
        var updatedPage = bookToUpdate.Pages.First(p => p.Id == pageToUpdate.Id);
        db.Entry(pageToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedPage);
    }
}
```

You can also use `DbContext.Update` method. this method results in the entity being tracked by the context as Modified. Once again, the context doesn't have any way of identifying which property values have been changed, and will generate SQL to update all properties. Where this method differs from explicitly setting the State property.